# Is it good practice for a class to use class methods to "manage" instances of itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I find that I have alot of occasions where I have a class that will usually need to be instantiated as a "collection".  My solution has always been to do something like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  def initialize bar
    @bar = bar
  end
end

class FooCollection
  attr_accessor :foos
  def initialize
    (0.10).each {|n| @foos[n] = Foo.new(n)}
    @coolest = 3
  end

  def coolest
    @foos[@coolest]
  end
end
```

I have thought about using class methods for this type of behavior.  I can't seem to make up my mind as to whether it is cleaner or messier to do this.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  @@all = []
  def self.create_all
    (0.10).each {|n| @@all[n] = Foo.new(n)}
    @@coolest = 3
  end

  def self.coolest
    @@all[@@coolest]
  end

  def initialize bar
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

I know using class methods creates an issue with it being a singleton, so if I needed to make multiple collections of foo I might have to make the collection a hash of arrays or something.  But really, neither of these solutions look "clean" to me, and when that's the case usually there is a better option that I'm unaware of.  Is there one?

Comment: It might help to use an actual scenario because I can't really follow your foobar code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm fairly a newbie, but I thought this would be a simple example. It is just creating a collection of 10 objects, and having some kind of designation that the object itself couldn't know about.  In this case I chose "coolest".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea you might like:

```
class FooCollection < Array

  def initialize
    super
    (0..10).each { |n| self[n] = Foo.new n }
    @coolest = 3
  end

  def coolest
    self[@coolest]
  end

end
```

Comment: Or you could use `def_delegators :@foos, :[]` if you prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to "what alternatives do I have?", I can't speak as someone who has learned how to do things properly, just as someone who had done things improperly.

I'd say avoid the singleton. You may think there's only going to be one of something, but that can change for reasons no-one can anticipate. I know there's "You ain't gonna need it", but this time, think of it as "you ain't gonna need the singleton", not "you ain't gonna need the ability to do multiple FooCollections".

If `FooCollection` sounds silly, don't use that as a reason to have a singleton. Try to work out what's using `FooCollection`. If there's only one thing using FooCollection, say `Bazza`, then maybe have the code handling the `Foo`s in `Bazza`, or a module that gets included into `Bazza`. Otherwise, if there's several objects using `FooCollection`, just try putting as many methods as you can into `FooCollection`, until that gives you an idea of what to rename it.